# Pass data from one form to next

Tags: c#, winforms

First form a couple of textboxes with Id, Name, Address, phonenumber

I want these to follow to the next form that has the same textboxes and a couple of more with message and extra and then choose between active and closed. Then I want it to be in different listviews. One with all the active and one with all the closed ones.

I want to be able to get all the info when I press one of the saved in the listviews.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you creating your second form from your first form? If so you can either pass your information in the second forms constructor or you can create property's on the second form and pass your information in that way.

Comment: I want the information to go from form1 to form2. 
The input for the user is in form1 and then it is only message and extra as input for the user in form 2. I am not sure what you mean but i hope this answer will make it more clear for you to understand what I mean

Answer (score 2):

what do you mean by active and closed?

for passing data between forms you can see this for a headstart :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms

Comment: I want to have different cases. The ones that are active and the ones that are closed.

Comment: what is active and closed ? (the textboxes ?)

Comment: Oh sorry! I want to choose in a dropdown list if the case is active or closed. Then I want it to be shown in two listviews one with all the active ones and one with all the closed ones.

Comment: So I want all the information about one case saved as closed or active. I hope you understand what I mean

Comment: what is a case ?
(you might implement 'case' as a class with a property IsActive and fill in the list views accordingly)

Comment: Okay i will give it another try and then see if he code works. If it doesn't work I will post all the code here

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this two examples:
1.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0ced05a-e930-4ffd-8ead-1004b9c579a4/passing-values-from-one-windows-form-to-another-windows-form-using-cnet
2.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171925.aspx

Comment: Thanks I will have a look I think the first one might help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Form1 Code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            frm2 frmnew2 = new frm2();
            frmnew2.Id = Convert.ToInt32(TxtId.Text);
            frmnew2.EmpName = TxtName.Text;
            frmnew2.Add = TxtAdd.Text;
            this.Hide();
            frmnew2.Show();
 }
```

Form2 Code

```
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public string Add { get; set; }

   private void frm2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
           TxtId.Text = Id.ToString();
           TxtName.Text =EmpName;
           TxtAdd.Text = Add;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this looks great!
Do you know if I can save it to a list and get it from that list because I have a couple of more forms that I want to output it in and get all the info by the Id that I give each one?

Comment: you load data in each form ?

Comment: Yeah I want to save the data to a list and then load it in each form